# How do you make Ketchup Doritos?

Tags: restaurant-mimicry, tortilla, chips, ketchup

I have been craving these for years, and I can't find a recipe.

Frito-Lay made Ketchup flavored Doritos a few years ago. Unfortunately they didn't sell very well and were discontinued not to long after being introduced. Me and a few friends were obsessed with them. I won't admit to how many bags I ate, but it consumed most of my snack budget :)

I've called Frito-Lay many times, and talked to a few of their delivery staffers about their lack of Ketchup Doritos, and the response was not good. The chance of them ever coming back is very bad.

So I turn to my last hope: Making them myself! Do you have a recipe for them? Even if it isn't the actual recipe, if it's your own proprietary blend I'm willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Since the powers that be don't want this site turning into a recipe swap, you're probably not going to get many answers. However, I did get some decent hits on Google when I worded the query like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+ketchup+chips (BTW: I'm not being a smartass. It took me a while to get Google to stop showing me homemade recipes of xyz with ketchup as an ingredient or condiment.)

Comment: This question is so wistful, it breaks my heart.

Comment: @dinah this isn't a run of the mill "GIMME TEH RECIPEZZ!" question, though, is it? This one is interesting, specific, and unique.

Comment: I know this question is getting old, but Frito-Lay does make Ketchup Lays chips. Not the same as Doritos but the "flavor" may be similar.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a recipe, but if you had say a dehydrator, ketchup, and whatsit--dextrose?--that helps dry things resist clumping, you could make your own. I believe Ferran Adria carries a powder product, on his website albertyferranadria.com.

Add the powder to your own tortilla chips that you've just fried, and should work.

Alternatively, multiplex movie theatres often have several different shakers of flavourings--cheese, sour cream/onion, that sort of thing. Perhaps Costco would carry something similar.

Comment: +1 because it's a step in the right direction :D I'll keep the question open in case someone does have a specific recipe/method :)

Comment: Not sure you can order it online, but http://www.clubhouse.ca/en/products/detail.aspx?Ketchup_Pop-corn_Seasoning&id=67de4917-3047-4739-adfa-e89712fdb895&category_id=9883809a-4c7e-4535-8922-445bf6e54cc6 is an ordinary grocery store item here in Canada - it's popcorn seasoning but you could sprinkle it on warm tortilla chips.

Answer (score 2):

Canada sells ketchup chips all the time. You could buy some there if you're close to the border. Otherwise you could buy ketchup powder and sprinkle those on regular potato chips, or buy some at ebay/amazon.

Comment: do you have ketchup corn chips?  (doritos are corn, not potato, but +1 for the ketchup powder suggestion ... might have to make your own ... tomato, garlic & onion powders, a little sugar, afix with vinegar)